# Delete all data after a | in data column

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub

I have dataframe that has | in one of the column data. I want to drop the | and everything to the right of it.

```
           X A B C D
1     uc001aaa.3              0              0              0              0
2     uc010nxq.1              0              0              0              0
3     uc010nxr.1              0              0              0              0
4  WASH7P|653635            398            319            453            259
5 FAM138F|641702              0              0              0             13
6    OR4F5|79501              0              0              0              0
```

What I have tried and isn't working:

```
Data$Test <- sub("\\|+*", "", Data$X)
```

Test column is deleting pipe, but leaving everything to the right. How do I add the deletion to the right of the | deletion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you're repeating the `|` while you probably want to repeat anything after the `|`, so you want `|.+`.

```
gsub('\\|.+', '', x)
# [1] "uc001aaa.3" "uc010nxq.1" "uc010nxr.1" "WASH7P"     "FAM138F"    "OR4F5"
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c("uc001aaa.3", "uc010nxq.1", "uc010nxr.1", "WASH7P|653635", 
"FAM138F|641702", "OR4F5|79501")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tidyverse with `str_remove()`:

```
df <- tibble(column = c("uc001aaa.3", "uc010nxq.1", "uc010nxr.1", "WASH7P|653635", 
       "FAM138F|641702", "OR4F5|79501"))

# A tibble: 6 × 1
  column        
  <chr>         
1 uc001aaa.3    
2 uc010nxq.1    
3 uc010nxr.1    
4 WASH7P|653635 
5 FAM138F|641702
6 OR4F5|79501
```

You can use:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(column = str_remove(string = column, 
                             pattern = "\\|.*"))


# A tibble: 6 × 1
  column    
  <chr>     
1 uc001aaa.3
2 uc010nxq.1
3 uc010nxr.1
4 WASH7P    
5 FAM138F   
6 OR4F5
```